# How to load the image?

Tags: android

I tried by calling the camera then image show, but in the `API 23` show 
**"Cannot load the image!"** by Toast. In `API 16` can run normally. I am testing in the inside of the virtual machine.I guess that is because the Runtime Permission of reason cannot write the cause of the storage space.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    takephoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.take_photo);
    picture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture);
    takephoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkPermission();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case TAKE_PHOTO:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
                intent.setDataAndType(imageUri, "image/*");
                intent.putExtra("scale", true);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CROP_PHOTO);
            }
            break;
        case CROP_PHOTO:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().
                            openInputStream(imageUri));
                    picture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            break;
        default:break;
    }
}

final int WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 123;
protected void checkPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.
                WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE );
    }
    File outputImage = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            "output_image.jpg");
    try {
        if (outputImage.exists()) {
            outputImage.delete();
        }
        outputImage.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(outputImage);
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
         String permission[], int []grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 &&
            grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                File outputImage = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        "output_image.jpg");
                try {
                    if (outputImage.exists()) {
                        outputImage.delete();
                    }
                    outputImage.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                imageUri = Uri.fromFile(outputImage);
                Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your app runs successfully in older APIs, then your problem is very likely to be related to permissions added to recent APIs.

More information here: http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html

My guess is you implemented Storage permission checking but forgot to implement Camera permission checking. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html